# Algorithm that fills entries diagonally

Tags: matrix

Suppose i have a matrix `A` of `n*n` and want to fill entries diagonally. 
First i want to fill main diagonal then the diagonal above the main diagonal and up to so on.
Then diagonal below the main diagonal

[image]

First i want to fill main diagonal that is in `red` color, then the diagonal above it that is in `green` color, then diagonal below main diagonal that is in `purple` color.

Then main concept is after then main diagonal is filled i want to fill the diagonal above it ,then below it, then above it, the below it until matrix is filled.

Suppose i have entries `1-64` that i want to fill diagonally.

Comment: What have you tried?  What language are you using?  How is the memory laid out?

Comment: @paddy i am just trying to write algorithm, not in any particular language

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Assume you have a subroutine that draws a single diagonal. How many times would it need to be called? What should it do? Can you spot if there is any pattern between coordinates of a same colour?

Comment: @Amadan yes there is pattern between coordinates of diagonals. need to be called 15 times because there total 15 diagonals of which two diagonals have 1 entry each

Comment: @paddy i tried to do it using 1d array and write it in 8 ,8 pairs so that it looks like matrix. and then spot that every in diagonal is +9 times previous.  i mean to say that if i look in main diagonal A[1],A[10],A[28], .., A[64]. every location is +9 times previous, same hold for other diagonals

Comment: @Amadan can you please tell me, is there any specific name to given to diagonals of matrix other than main diagonal

Comment: What you have is a [pentadiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix); I guess "non-main diagonal"? Not a mathematician though. You'd have more fun thinking about five diagonals than 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there is no language or information about your matrix set up...

A good strategy would be:

- As always check for nulls and IOO exceptions on your own.

  1. Starting at [0,0] fill in the first diagonal line using a loop. (a11, a22, ...)
  2. Loop with condition row/col < dimension, since it's an n*n
  3. Two more loops inside previous loop. The first loop should do another diagonal line above the first (a12, a23 ..). The second loop should do the diagonal line below it...

Here's something I ran quickly. Hope it helps.

NOTE: Where it says *//Do something..* is where you need to change your cell to do whatever you need. I would assume you're using objects that would change color..?

```
package temp;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DiagFiller {

private int dimension;

public DiagFiller(int dimension){
    int[][] matrix = new int[dimension][dimension];

    // Initialize your array cells.
    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
            matrix[row][col] = 0; // Initialize matrix value here
        }
    }

    // For middle initial diagonal
    for(int row = 0; row < dimension; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < dimension; col++){
            if(row == col){
                // Do something to this cell.
            }
        }
    }

    // For filling rest of matrix
    for(int i = 1; i < dimension*2; i++){

        // Loop for above diagonals.
        int row = 0;
        int col = i;
        while(col < dimension){
            matrix[row][col] = i; // Do something to above diagonal.
            row++;
            col++;
        }

        // Loop for below diagonals.
        row = i;
        col = 0;
        while(row < dimension){
            matrix[row][col] = i; // Do something to below diagonal.
            row++;
            col++;
        }
    }

    // Print your array cells.
    for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    DiagFiller df = new DiagFiller(8);
}
```

}

Comment: while loop in Loop for above diagonals will fill one diagonal at a time?

Comment: int row should not be initialized with 1

Comment: Yes it will go in the order you mentioned filling each diagonal from Top/Left to Bottom/Right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about int row not be initialized with 1? I'm just using integers here to show how it could be filled. I would assume you would initialize each cell with a object you've created.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem just to give you rough idea how it can be achieved.

It can be further generalised based on your requirements.

My code is in java and you can see it here :http://ideone.com/L4zu2j

Edited for those who need spoon feeding -_-

```
    /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n= 6;
        int a[][] = new int[n][n];

        // for upper half 
        for(int p=0 ; p < n ; p ++){

            for(int i = 0 + p ; i< n ; i++){
                a[i-p][i] = p + 100;
            }
        }

            // for lower half 
        for(int p=1 ; p < n ; p ++){

            for(int i = 0  ; i< n -p ; i++){
                a[i+p][i] = p - 100;
            }
        }

        // printing array
        for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i ++){
                for(int j=0 ; j < n ; j ++){
                    System.out.print(a[i][j] + "   ");
        }


        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Output

```
100   101   102   103   104   105   
-99   100   101   102   103   104   
-98   -99   100   101   102   103   
-97   -98   -99   100   101   102   
-96   -97   -98   -99   100   101   
-95   -96   -97   -98   -99   100
```

Hope this helps. Ask if any doubt.

Comment: updated the generalised solution, hope this helps now.